# Instanceof for objects in c++ (not pointers)

Tags: c++, object, stack

If I have the following classes :

```
class Object { ... } 

class MyClass1: public Object { ... } 

class MyClass2: public Object { ... }
```

and a stack : `std::stack<Object> statesObjects;`

```
MyClass1 c1;
MyClass2 c2;

statesObjects.push(c1); // okay
statesObjects.push(c2); // okay
```

How can I pop them out and retrieve the element at the head of the stack (with `top()` ) without `dynamic_cast`  , since I don't work with pointers here ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is, that with your stack as-is you can't pop out the elements as derived-class type elements. By putting them into the stack you have **sliced** them to the element class of the stack. That is, only that base class part has been copied into the stack.

You can have a stack of pointers, however, and then you can use `dynamic_cast` provided that the statically known class has at least one `virtual` member function, or as the standard says, provided that the statically known class is **polymorphic**.

On the third and gripping hand, however, instead of the Java-like downcast *use a virtual function in the common base class*. Often it works to just directly have such a function. For more complicated scenarios you may have to use the **visitor pattern** (google it), but basically, the idea is that virtual functions are the “safe” language-supported type safe way to achieve the effect of downcasts.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pop them out to their original classes, when you assign a subclass to an instance of the superclass, it gets [sliced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) into an instance of the superclass. i.e copies of `c1` and `c2` which are in the `stack` are now instances of `Object` and not their original classes

Similar to [How can I make the method of child be called: virtual keyword not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907522/how-can-i-make-the-method-of-child-be-called-virtual-keyword-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

Even if you seeminlgy store a derived class object in your class, what gets stored is only the Base class part of the object. In short You get **Object Slicing**.

To summarize, you cannot store derived class objects in this container. You will need to store a pointer to Base as the type of conainter and use dynamic polymorphism to acheive this.

Good Read:
[What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)